# AJAX call from a popup modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, bootstrap-modal

Trying to call an AJAX request from a modal popup.

```
function exportReport(){
$.ajax({
        url : 'exportReport',
        data : {
            from : fromDate,
            to : toDate
        },
        success : function(responseText) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
    }
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/exportReport")
public class GenerateReportServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```

main.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<head>
....................
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="exportReport()">Export</button>
</div>
....................
</html>
```

main.jsp is inside `webapps\views`. This export button is in a popup modal div. Click on Export is calling,

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/views/exportReport?from=1465972200000&to=1465107600000` and is HTTP Status 404. It should come like `http://localhost:8080/myApp/exportReport?from=1465972200000&to=1465107600000`. How that `/views/` is coming in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific when setting the url, else it will be appended to the current url.

Use `url : '/myApp/exportReport'` instead in the AJAX call.

The leading slash indicates that the url is *absolute*.

Omitting the leading slash makes the url *relative* to the current url.

Comment: Its working. But report is not getting generated. But when I paste the url in a browser manually, its getting generated Seems strange.. Checked the servlet.

Comment: Must be something on your server side, for example how the data is received.. Try setting ajax `method` to `GET` and `dataType` to `html`. See the API for more/alternative ajax properties: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/